# Understanding summations in COV formula for time series

Tags: time-series, sum

I am looking through [Time Series Analysis: With Applications in R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441926135) (my first exposure to time series) and refreshing summations.

*I.*
When given the following rule:

COV[$\sum_{i=1}^{m} c_{i}Y_{t_{i}},\sum_{j=1}^{n} d_{j}Y_{s_{j}}$] = $\sum_{i=1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_{i}d_{j}Cov(Y_{t_{i}},Y_{s_{j}})$

and then encounter COV{$\frac{e_{t}+e_{t-1}}{2},\frac{e_{t-1}+e_{t-2}}{2}$}

in order to use the rule, do you need to re-write the summations so that they match the rule, like this:

COV[$\sum_{i=0}^{1}\frac{1}{2}e_{t-i},\sum_{j=1}^{2}\frac{1}{2}e_{t-j} $] or is there a different way to think about these summation?

Another example:
*II.*
Given that Var[$\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}Y_{t_{i}}] =\sum_{i=1}^{n}c^{2}Var(Y_{t_{i}})+ 2\sum_{i=2}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}c_{i}c_{j}Cov(Y_{t_{i}},Y_{t_{j}})$

to compute Var[$\frac{e_{t}+e_{t-1}}{2}$]

how would you set this up?

*III.* What do you do in II. when the summation in the last portion starts at i=2? My  method from I. (trying to rewrite the summation to fit the problem) seems to breaks down.
How should these be considered?

Comment: What "rule" are you citing in part I?  You do not supply a right hand side.  In III, what is "your method"?

Comment: Oops, I appear to have gotten tired of typing ;-) I added the right hand side. My question is mainly how to use summation rules and apply these to the shown problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have another rule which for your case is simpler:
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{\mathbb{Cov}} \DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{\mathbb{Var}}
 \Cov(a X, b Y) = a b \Cov(X,Y)
$$
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) which is a generalization of the following rule for variance: $\Var(a X) = a^2 \Var X$. After using this rule you can expand the summations.